# How to use YAML front matter variables contained in an SVG file

Tags: svg, yaml, jekyll, github-pages

recently I have been using Jekyll with Github Pages to host my blog/webcomic. How should I go about using YAML front matter data in an SVG file in my webcomic/blog? I can add it to the SVG's, however it will not allow me to read the data from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be impossible. I have recently moved to a more feasible custom build system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are allowed to use front-matter in a file with an SVG extension. I would use an `{% include myimage.svg %}` and call the `{{ page.frontmattervariable }}` from within the SVG file. That should work.